# Telnet not working for os.system call

Tags: python, command-line, telnet, os.system, telnetlib

Why cant I call the following in python using os?

```
import os
os.system('telnet 1.1.1.1')
```

yet when I open a terminal and use the exact command, I can telnet. I get the following when running the code:

> 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I have enabled TelnetClient and TelnetServer

Comment: so if you open a shell and type `which telnet` what do you get? (on windows use `where telnet.exe`)

Comment: windows 7 - C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe

Comment: try printing `sys.path` is `C:\Windows\System32` included in the path?

Comment: As a side note, you better use Popen to interact with telnet: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor . Unless your idea is just let the user interact with it and not your python script.

Comment: Is it possible to use python to send login info to telnet? For example, send a username (user) and password(pass) to the host (1.1.1.1) so that it auto logs in?

somehow send a string to a process that just called telnet? I want to avoid using external programs, but methods or hard-coded solutions work

Comment: Check that Popen function, it will let you control stdin, stderr and stdout. Also the @mK7 method using the telnet lib is cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jon S.: Programs like Telnet and SSH are interactive in nature. So when you open a telnet it will return something from the shell it is running to handle that particular connection. I haven't tried running the command like you mentioned above but I have used 'telnetlib' of python in Windows successfully in the past and still using it. Here is a snippet that can be of help.

```
import telnetlib
import os

host_ip = "1.1.1.1"
user = "user"
password = "password"

tnet_hndl = telnetlib.Telnet(host_ip)
print (tnet_hndl.read_until(b"login: "))
tnet_hndl.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
print (tnet_hndl.read_until(b"Password: "))
tnet_hndl.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
print (tnet_hndl.read_until(b"# "))
#tnet_hndl.set_debuglevel(1) #enable this if you want to debug more
tnet_hndl.write(b"<enter some windows cmd here>" + b"\n")
print (tnet_hndl.read_until(b"# "))
tnet_hndl.close()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: this helps a little - I've already took a look at stuff like this. My issue with this type of code is that my code gets suck while trying to read - I just executed the above and it hung up at print tnet_hndl.read_until(b"login: "). I'm not sure why, but I cant get past any of the .read_until functions

Comment: You will have to replace the b"login: " with whatever prompt you get while you use telnet from Windows to your destination machine.

Comment: Does spacing matter? When I telnet normally, I get "User Name:  a" where the a represents the start of where i can type the username. I assume I would want to do this? print (tnet_hndl.read_until(b"User Name: ")) with one space? I've tried 1 and 2 spaces but still no luck...

Comment: Amazing what a little debugging can do... my issue was the '#' was actually a '>' thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't forget to 1-up the answer if you found it useful. :-)

Comment: i need 15 rep... or i totally would! >.<

Answer (score 0):

Just try `os.system('C:/Windows/System32/telnet.exe  1.1.1.1 <port number>')` and see what happens?

Comment: 'C:\Windows\System32\telnet.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: The port is 23 - shouldn't that be fine since it is set as default?

Comment: Okay so I tried calling the following:
os.startfile("C:/Windows/System32/telnet.exe")
and got an interesting result: 
No such file: C:\\Windows\\System32\telnet.exe

Why is it adding additional slashes even though I am not supplying them?

Comment: The first slash is to escape the second. In strings `\ ` is used to create escape characters like newline (`\n`) or tab (`\t`), so you have to add two of them to say it's just an slash.